# Sum of sequence of non-identical random variables. Can they become something else than Normal distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, soft-question, fourier-analysis, central-limit-theorem

The [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is well known in statistics. It states:

```
When there is a large number of random variables with same random distribution 
and finite second order moment the mean value of these variables will tend 
to the normal distribution
```

If we remove one of these constraints: **same** random distribution. What is the "simplest" (in some suitable sense) sequence of random distributions we can prove won't tend to normal distribution?

Comment: No, you didn't state CLT correctly.  You need finiteness of second moment, and it is the mean, not the sum, that tends to the normal distribution.

Comment: @user10354138 mm ok, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sufficient condition for the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to hold is that the variables (besides having finite variance) are independent and identically distributed. It can also hold for [not identically distributed variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT), but then some additional conditions on the moments are necessary.

A typical example in which the conditions are not fullfilled is an autoregresive process: let $x_n= a x_{n-1} + e_n$ where $|a|<1$ and $e_n$ is iid (white noise) following some distribution with (say) zero mean and finite variance $\sigma^2_e$.

Then, solving that iteratively in terms of $e_n$ we get

$$\begin{align}x_n&=e_n + a e_{n-1} + a^2 e_{n-2} + \cdots\\
&= u_0 + u_{1}+u_{2}+ \cdots
\end{align}$$

where $u_{k}=a^k e_{n-k}$ are independent random variables, but not identically distributed (in particular, $Var(u_k)= a^{2k} \sigma^2_e$)

That $x_n$ does not  follow a normal distribution in general (it's of course normal if $e_n$ is normal) can be seen by considering a bounded $e_n$, for example, $e_n \sim U[-1,1]$. In this case $|x_n|\le 1 + a + a^2 \cdots = (1-a)^{-1}$, hence $x_n$ is also bounded, it cannot be normal.

Comment: Interesting. This Lyapunov was onto something!